# Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.ts(2345)

Tags: typescript

Получаю ошибку, при попытке добавить объект CartItem в массив foods.

```
Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.ts(2345)
```

Я так понимаю, что проблема в том, что foods объявлен без указания типа.

```
foods: []
```

Как решить эту проблему?

```
export class CartService {
  items$: CartItem[] = [];
  constructor() {
    this.items$ = [];
  }
  getItemsInCart() {
    return this.items$;
  }
}

export class CartItem {
    quantity = 1; 
    food: any;  
    constructor(food: any) {
      this.food = food;
    }  
}



export class CartComponent implements OnInit {
  model = {
    Name: '',
    State: '',
    foods: []
  };

  constructor(private cart: CartService) {    
  }
  ngOnInit() {}
  onSubmit() {
    this.cart.getItemsInCart().forEach(cartItem => {
      this.model.foods.push(cartItem.food);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Эм, ну добавить объявление типа?

Comment: а если мне тут нужен именно any?

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо типизировать вашу переменную model

```
type ModelType = {
  Name: string;
  State: string
  foods: any[];
};

const model: ModelType = {
  Name: '',
  State: '',
  foods: [],
}

model.foods.push('строка');
model.foods.push(1); // число
model.foods.push([]);
model.foods.push({});
```